# Justice of Allah when creating humans

Tags: hadith, allah, justice, divine-justice

Some people out of hardship or being feared that they might end up in hell, Wished that they never exist in the first place. And there is this question,

*Why did Allah created me when I don't want to exist?*

One answer I heard is that, Allah asked everyone if they want to enter the test or be human beings. They said yes.

But I never got reference for it. Closest thing I can get is a Hadith about Adam As taking responsibility, and a Quran ayah talking about

> “Truly, We did offer al-amaanah (the trust or moral responsibility or
> honesty and all the duties which Allah has ordained) to the heavens
> and the earth, and the mountains, but they declined to bear it and
> were afraid of it (i.e. afraid of Allah’s torment). But man bore it.
> Verily, he was unjust (to himself) and ignorant (of its results)

[al-Ahzaab 33:72]”.

But in tafsir in ibn kathir. Choosing that whether to take amaanah or not is only given to Adam AS not to every human being. So in sort Adam As took the responsibility behalf of All human beings. **Which some people will argue as injustice,**

So can anyone help me to find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just dispute their baseless argument that it is unjust. If they wish to claim it is unjust, the burden of proof is on them.

It is not unjust at all. The test isn’t something evil such that Allah needs to take people’s consent before they are put in it. The test is entirely fair, and Allah can test people without them having agreed to it.

Some people might object and say: How is it fair if I didn’t want to be tested? What if I didn’t want to exist or I wanted to be inanimate?

I would respond with: Who said your wants matter?

Inequality is not the same as unfairness. You are not equal to the mountains or other inanimate objects. We already agree to that. But, to prove something unfair, you need to show you are being denied some rights you have. There are no rights being denied here. Something going against your wants is not a violation of rights.

You do not have the right to be free from tests. Allah can test you if He wants. You are His slaves, and He is your owner. Whether you like it or not, you are in the test and will face the consequences of your actions.

If you claim you do have the right not to be tested, bring your evidence.

Also see: [Did humans choose to be tested?](http://blog.fussilat.com/did-humans-choose-to-be-tested/)

Comment: Your link is not working

Comment: @Yusha Should work now.

Comment: Even as a Muslim, the answer feels less like an “answer” and more like a threat…. This could have been explained in a much better way

Answer (score 0):

> And [mention] when your Lord took from the children of Adam - from
> their loins - their descendants and made them testify of themselves,
> [saying to them], "Am I not your Lord?" They said, "Yes, we have
> testified." [This] - lest you should say on the Day of Resurrection,
> "Indeed, we were of this unaware.
>
> ~ [Quran 7-172](https://quran.com/7/172)

Comment: I already know that verse but that doesn't really answers the question. Allah didn't asked them to take responsibility or amaanah

Answer (score 0):

Amanah is to testify that the lord and creator is Allah, in a form of trust:

> We did indeed offer the Trust to the Heavens and the Earth and the Mountains; but they refused to undertake it, being afraid thereof: but man undertook it;- He was indeed unjust and foolish;

Allah also said:

> And I created not the Jinn and mankind except that they should worship Me.

Meaning, to testify that there is only one creator with no association.

Allah in another verse said:

> What can Allah gain by your punishment, if ye are grateful and ye
> believe? Nay, it is Allah that recogniseth (all good), and knoweth all
> things.

Hence, the purpose of creating us is not to feel pure pain, rather to believe as per humans promised and agreed to participate in this test, after all other creatures refused to take the Amanah.

Allah said:

> When thy Lord drew forth from the Children of Adam - from their loins - their descendants, and made them testify concerning themselves, (saying): "Am I not your Lord (who cherishes and sustains you)?"- They said: "Yea! We do testify!" (This), lest ye should say on the Day of Judgment: "Of this we were never mindful".

So, Adam did not take the responsibility on behalf of all humans, rather everyone of us did and accepted the test, individually.

When Adam did the first sin and repented to Allah, it was the "sign" that Adam (as a new creature) is **now ready** to start the journey of the worldly life, as he showed that he has proved that he is able to take the first decision independently, so his offspring can do too, because there is no obligatory to become a Muslim, hence the true test indeed, it is up to the human to choose to fulfill or to deny what he/she has promised to do when they participated in the test willingly.

Comment: My question was not purpose of creation though. And can you give me any references from a good scholar commentary or any credible source that says that testifying Allah is Lord means taking the amaanah, From the Hadith you quoted.

Comment: I don't know where from you get the definition of amaanah but the definition of amaanah in ibn kathir is : "Al-Amanah means obedience. This was offered to them before it was offered to Adam, and they could not bear it."

Comment: @Yusha "*The word amaanah includes all religious duties, according to the correct scholarly view, which is the view of the majority*" And you know that the first pillar in Islam is to testify that there is only one God. [Look here for full details](https://islamqa.info/en/232749).
Now regarding your question, you seem to be not knowing what you're really looking for, or at least you are moving the goalposts.
P.S you omitted the phrase "in a form of trust" when you quoted my words.